# Silly CMake question: how to read INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES from target?

Tags: cmake

Here's my `CMakeLists.txt` - the only file in the directory:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.4 FATAL_ERROR)
project(dummy LANGUAGES NONE)

add_library(version INTERFACE EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
target_include_directories(version INTERFACE
        version/include)

get_cmake_property(dirs TARGET version PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message(STATUS "version's INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES using generic property: ${dirs}")

get_target_property(dirs version INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message(STATUS "version's INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES using target property: ${dirs}")

get_cmake_property(dirs TARGET version PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message(STATUS "version's INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES using generic property: ${dirs}")

get_target_property(dirs version INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message(STATUS "version's INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES target property: ${dirs}")
```

Here's the output:

```
 $ mkdir build
 $ cd build
 $ cmake ..
-- version's INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES using generic property: NOTFOUND
-- version's INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES using target property: dirs-NOTFOUND
-- version's INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES using generic property: NOTFOUND
-- version's INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES target property: /home/adam/cmake_bug/version/include
-- Configuring done (0.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/Adama-docs/Adam/linux/tmp/cmake_bug/build
```

Can someone explain me, why I cannot read the included directory back?

Ultimately, I want to read the directory using generator expression, but no wonder it does not work if the direct property access fails.

I use CMake 3.26.4 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

1. I've used the wrong function: I should have called `get_property` instead.
2. Another thing is that the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` is a completely distinct property from `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`. Setting the `PUBLIC` include directory sets both, and setting the INTERFACE include directory sets only `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`.

Everything works correct now, including my generator expressions.